# Facebook og:image (link image) does not display when sharing my website

Tags: facebook, share-open-graph

I cannot get the image to show when sharing my site in FB. Below is my open graph code.

I have rescraped using the FB sharing debugging tool (https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug). soooo many times, and it never displays, in the tool or in a share.

The debugger reports no errors, and lists the correct image.

The image is 1200x630 and exists on the same site.

Using open graph checker displays the expected image.
https://iplocation.io/open-graph-checker.

I have tried everything i can find in posts. but i really need this working for marketing.

Hope someone has the secret sauce.

cheers,

```
    <meta property="fb:app_id" content="123456789"/>
    <meta property="og:type" content="website"/>
    <meta property="og:image" content="http://www.example.com/images/og2.jpg"/>
    <meta property="og:image:secure_url" content="https://www.example.com/images/og2.jpg"/>
    <meta property="og:image:type" content="image/jpeg" />
    <meta property="og:title" content="my title"/>
    <meta property="og:description" content="my description."/>
    <meta property="og:image:width" content="1200"/>
    <meta property="og:image:height" content="630"/>
```

Comment: What URL are you sharing?